# Creating drop down list in ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

I'm trying to create a drop down list in ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder.
The goal is to have a list of different vegetation types that then will be used for further analysis (e.g. mangroves, saltmarsh, seagrass).
I've created a String Variable and have been able to create the actual list.
How do I link the strings to the actual shapefile? Or how would I proceed from here?
[image]

Comment: In ArcGIS for desktop the value of the dropdown list is represented as a variable by the marker %ValueListFilter%, perhaps Pro is the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the limited screen shot you have provided you have connected your list as a precondition to the pairwise tool. You are not showing where you intend to use the select vegetation type.  I'm going to **guess** you want to select some polygons that are for example Mangrove then do something on that selection?  You would use the chosen value by using inline variable substitution, read the help file on that.

Because you variable is named *Which Vegetation Type?* then to access it in a select by attributes tool you would reference it something like `myField = "%Which Vegetation Type?%"`  where myField is your vegetation class field name.